# Do we do algorithm analysis based on a model of computation or do we do it based on "common sense"?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, analysis

Recently, I was reading these books about algorithms, specifically the section about analysis of algorithms:

- Introduction to Algorithms. 3rd ed. TCRC
- Algorithm Design Manual. 2nd ed. S. Skiena
- Algorithm Design. J.Kleinberg & Eva Tardos
- Algorithms. 4th ed. R. Sedgewick
- Algorithms. S. Dasgupta, C. Papadimitriou & Vazirani
- a few other books

After that, I got a bit confused because I don't fully understand the origin of counting steps of algorithms.

I mean, in Introduction to Algorithms and Algorithm Design Manual, something called the RAM model of computation is mentioned. In these books, it is said that under that model we count steps, but in the others books a model of computation as such is not mentioned.

The other books talk about counting steps of the path that the algorithm travels, that is, in a common sense way or in a logical way. So, I would appreciate if you guys could help me with these questions:

What's the relationship(or difference) between the step count method (other books) and using a model of computation (TCRC & S. Skiena) to do it?
When someone talks about counting steps to analyze algorithms, may I assume he is referring to using a model of computation(RAM)?

Comment: It's all of the above and none of the above. In fact, arguing about what constitutes a step is the second favorite pastime of academics when discussing algorithm complexity. See for example [this discussion about the complexity of a radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Efficiency).

Comment: @user3386109 what's it second to?

Answer (score 4):

Our common sense is based on a model of computation that can be implicit or explicit.  Usually in an introductory course it is left implicit.  Explicitly what you use is usually the RAM model.  Which is based on the idea of sequential processing, where each simple operation takes constant time.  So you just count steps.

You can find a formal description of that model at http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~cs125/fall14/lec6.pdf.

Reality is, of course, rather different.  As https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832 shows, operations take wildly different amounts of time.  I've personally seen jobs go from 5 days to 1 hour by switching to using a sort instead of hash lookups.  Yes, hash lookups are `O(1)`, but with a horrible constant when data is backed by disk.  Distributed computing has things operating in parallel.  Computing on a GPU gives you a tremendous amount of parallelism..as long as all computation operates in perfect lockstep.  We are trying to build quantum computers, which can theoretically give would give us many, many orders of magnitude more parallelism..at the cost of losing irreversible operations like "if".

We can create models that deal with all of this complexity.  But there is no need to consider any of it until you understand the basics.  Which is the standard "count operations" thing from the RAM model.